# dynamically add row to table with data from the database

Tags: javascript, jstl

I am using JSTL to read data from a database and put it in my dropdown list like below

```
  <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
       SELECT name from accommodation;
  </sql:query>  

 Accommodation Type:*    
        <select name="accommodation" id="accommodation" required>
                <option value="">-- select one --</option>
                <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                  <option value="${row.name}"/>${row.name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
         </select>
```

Lets assume my database table looks like this

**id**     **name**
1      1 bedroom
2     2 bedrooms

Now I know that in order to add a row dynamically to the above table, I would use a JavaScript function similar to this

```
      var cellA = row.insertCell(0);
      var ele = document.createElement('select');
      var op1 = document.createElement('option');
      var op2 = document.createElement('option');
          op1.value = "1 bedroom";
          op1.innerHTML = "1 bedroom";
          op2.value = "2 bedrooms";
          op2.innerHTML = "2 bedrooms";   
              ele.appendChild(op1);
              ele.appendChild(op2);   
              ele.name = 'accommodation';
  cellA.appendChild(ele);
```

My question is, how can I dynamically add a row to the table without hardcoding the Value and InnerHTML? is there a way I can obtain the data directly from the database?

Comment: Everything is possible but... What is your database ? What have you tried to make it work ?

Comment: What do you mean what is my database? I believe there is a mock table shown in the question. You want to see the whole database?

Comment: @SKunda Sorry I misread the code. But I guess I do not understand the question... What are you trying to achieve with your javascript code ?

Comment: The html code is in a table and I'm trying to make the table dynamic so the javascript code adds a row to the table which is identical to the html code. The only problem is that for the html code I am querying the database but for the javascript I am hardcoding from the database. I want to query it instead